# Secure a slug in Symfony2.1

Tags: symfony

### How would you secure a slug in Symfony2.1?

A malicious user could append `";rm -rf *"` to the id value and delete the entire Website.  In symfony2.1, is there a simple way to secure the slugs?

I have tried to secure an id this way.

```
/**
 * The idea is to check that the slug cart_id is an id and not
 *
 * @Route("/{cart_id}/show", name="show_cart")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showCartAction($cart_id)
{

    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{2}$/", $cart_id))
    {
       throw new \Exception("the id is not correct");
    }

    $cart = $this->getCartManager()
        ->getCart($cart_id);

    return array(
        'cart'=> cart
    );
}
```

**Do you find this necessary? Would you do it this way ?**

Comment: I'm really curious how you think that `rm -rf` attack could possibly work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ensure that `cart_id` will always accept integer by adding requirements in `@Route` annotation. e.g

```
/**
 * @Route("/{cart_id}/show", name="show_cart", requirements={"cart_id" = ("\d+")})
 * @Template()
 */
```

But still there is almost zero chance that the attacker will execute malicious query via sql-injection as Doctrine2 uses PDO prepared statement with parametarized query. For more information about prepared statement with parametarized query see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134138/1218997).

Comment: It should be this instead: requirements={"cart_id" = "\d+"}